# bootstrap 2 background-colors in 1 row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I hope this question makes sense. I'm stummped at what to do. I am currently developing a site where a section of the page will have two seperate background colors (1 for the left and 1 for the right). This is what I am trying to go for:

```
<div class="gray-bg">
    <div class="span6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, consequuntur illo impedit libero nam voluptatem sed facere earum quam ullam velit iste necessitatibus aperiam dolor id. Quod rerum est vel.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="white-bg">
    <div class="span6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci quam sapiente ut iusto neque. Obcaecati, molestiae, consequuntur qui blanditiis libero odio fuga eum iusto illo eaque inventore ipsa eligendi ipsam!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried several varations of this, putting rows under the span, putting containers and subrows in the span, but I'm not able to create the affect I want. Can anyone please help out? Thanks!

Update: Heres a JSFiddle of what I am trying to do. It works, but its not in a container to space out the row correctly. When I put it in the container, The blue on the left does not extend all the way.

http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/622/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GTYT7/ Or just use Bootstrap 3. The Bootstrap 2 container/row/span system is a bit rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

try the following: [Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/134539)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="gray-bg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, consequuntur illo impedit libero nam voluptatem sed facere earum quam ullam velit iste necessitatibus aperiam dolor id. Quod rerum est vel.</p>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="white-bg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci quam sapiente ut iusto neque. Obcaecati, molestiae, consequuntur qui blanditiis libero odio fuga eum iusto illo eaque inventore ipsa eligendi ipsam!</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.gray-bg {
  background-color:red;
 }

.white-bg {
  background-color:green;
 }
```

Comment: I know how to do that but the spans and rows create padding. I want the colors to span across the entire section.

Comment: I've figured it out but the problem is I cant have a container otherwise the color will go away, meaning I'm not sure what to do to get the page spaced out correctly. I will post a jsfiddle

Comment: Or you just override the padding styles.

Comment: I could override the padding but I think I'd have to media query a lot to get it correct across the screen sizes, when having a container like structure makes that easier/better. any other thoughts?